# Bluetooth Headset lost connection

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have a new Corsair HS70 Bluetooth headset with an USB Adapter for my zoom meetings. But the connection is not reliable.

After a few connection attempts, it worked to connect the devices.
However, after restarting the system, the connection can no longer be established. Pairing exists and the headset is marked as trusted.

For a short time, the connection works and I hear the corresponding sound in the headset. After 1-2 seconds, however, the connection is interrupted again. Disconnecting Sound is heard in the headset and the output of `bluetoothctl` can be seen:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 20:06:10:12:D4:45 
Attempting to connect to 20:06:10:12:D4:45
[CHG] Device 20:06:10:12:D4:45 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 20:06:10:12:D4:45 Connected: no
```

In `dmesg` is only an `unexpected event` listed:

```
➜  ~ dmesg | egrep -i 'bluetooth|firm'
[    0.160124] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.170953] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
[    1.097982] usb 5-1: Product: HS70 BLUETOOTH Gaming Headset
[    1.969588] input: C-Media Electronics Inc. HS70 BLUETOOTH Gaming Headset as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0b:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.3/0003:1B1C:0A61.0001/input/input2
[    2.028679] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:0A61.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc. HS70 BLUETOOTH Gaming Headset] on usb-0000:0b:00.3-1/input3
[    3.772456] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.772475] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.772478] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.772481] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.772484] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.790889] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x0000
[    3.988450] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.7 DEC: 4 VEP: 0 Revision: 13
[    3.988467] [drm] PSP loading VCN firmware
[    5.524928] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.524930] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.524934] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   56.565537] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   56.565544] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   56.565549] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am still having a lot of trouble with bluetooth, but the following attempts may help you out.

This is something I personally used and worked for a while.

1st:Check if pulse-audio and its dependencies are installed:
sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-utils pavucontrol pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

2nd: When we verify it, we need to create or edit this audio config file:
sudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/audio.conf
Include the next lines:
#This section contains general options
[General]
Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Socket

3rd: Now it’s time to save the file and start the Bluetooth service again.
sudo service bluetooth restart

Link to full article: https://dev.to/campbelljones74/common-bluetooth-problems-in-ubuntu-and-how-to-fix-them-18b5

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. The problem is still the same. When restarting blueman the following error came up in journalctl 
Feb 19 13:07:14 desktop blueman.desktop[2844]: blueman-applet 13.07.14 WARNING  DiscvManager:109 update_menuitems: warning: Adapter is None
Feb 19 13:07:14 desktop blueman.desktop[2844]: blueman-applet 13.07.14 WARNING  DiscvManager:109 update_menuitems: warning: Adapter is None
Feb 19 13:07:14 desktop blueman.desktop[2844]: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Looks like it's python incompatibility, try following the article to update it:

https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-5hab

I am no specialist, let us know the results.

Comment: I am not that familiar with Python. Can it be a problem that I already have a newer version: python3 --version => Python 3.8.5. Have an Ubuntu 20.04.02 installed here.

Comment: No, it's usually not a problem to have a newer version, my last idea is to try the 3.9 version that is out in the wild. usually Ubuntu comes with Python 2 something...